# How to get rid of White rectangle from an image using java

Tags: java

I had tired the following code to generate the thumb nail but when I place it on another image, the thumbnail has a white rectangle. How can I remove it using java graphics 2D?

```
  Image image = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(new File(originalFile));       
  BufferedImage thumbImage = new BufferedImage(thumbWidth, thumbHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
  Graphics2D graphics2D = thumbImage.createGraphics();
  graphics2D.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
  graphics2D.setPaint(Color.WHITE); 
  graphics2D.fillRect(0, 0, thumbWidth, thumbHeight);       
  graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
  graphics2D.drawImage(image, 0, 0, thumbWidth, thumbHeight, null);   
  File file = new File(thumbnailFile);
  if(javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(thumbImage, "png", file))
      return file;
  }
```

Even if i remove these three lines I am getting black rectangle.

```
 graphics2D.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
 graphics2D.setPaint(Color.WHITE); 
 graphics2D.fillRect(0, 0, thumbWidth, thumbHeight);
```

How to get this image as transparent? Please some one help me out.

Comment: graphics2D.setBackground( new Color(0,0,0,0));
    graphics2D.setPaint( new Color(0,0,0,0)); 
    graphics2D.fillRect(0, 0, thumbWidth, thumbHeight);

Comment: Still i am getting the white rectangle when i place on another image.

Answer (score 2):

```
 Color transparent = new Color(0,0,0,0)
```

by setting `Composite` . [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#setComposite%28java.awt.Composite%29) : [AlphaComposite](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/AlphaComposite.html)

```
 // Create an image that supports arbitrary levels of transparency
 Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
 BufferedImage thumbImage = g2d.getDeviceConfiguration().createCompatibleImage(
    thumbWidth, thumbHeight, Transparency.TRANSLUCENT);
```

Comment: graphics2D.setBackground( new Color(0,0,0,0));
    graphics2D.setPaint( new Color(0,0,0,0)); 
    graphics2D.fillRect(0, 0, thumbWidth, thumbHeight);

Answer (score 2):

```
..BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB
```

That should be:

```
..BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB
```